# mysql php - check if last variable is the same

Tags: php

I tried to echo out the $rinse variable, I get nothing
But I do get one for the `$rang['email']`, any clues would be good
I also tried doing `$rinse == $rang['email'];`

```
while($rang = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
{
    if ($rang['email'] = $rinse){
        echo $rang['email'];
    }

    $rinse = $rang['email'];
}
```

**my code updated:**

```
echo $rinse; 
    if ($rang['email'] == $rinse){
         echo $rang['email']; 
        }
 $rinse = $rang['email']
```

This is still not working for me

Comment: are you saying that @Andrews answer below does not solve the issue for you?

Comment: I have added your comment into your original question, Peter

Comment: If your issue is still outstanding then you need to explain (edit your question and add details at the bottom under the code) what's not working. Also try outputting as much data as possible, doing `var_dump($rince)` and `var_dump($rang)` to check that your SQL is passing the data correctly to your PHP code.

Comment: If however the answer has fixed your problem, tick the tick arrow next to Andrews answer to indicate this.  :)

Comment: your **my code updated:** doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I'm also curious for a bit more context on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two `=` in your `if` statement.

`if ($rang['email'] == $rinse){`

Comment: Yup.  Must have written them at about the same time.

Comment: His was incorrect due to double equals in the while clause. And now he's deleted it.... ho hum....

Comment: :) Oh well.  Que sera.

Answer (score 0):

You should add double ==. This is comparion, a single = means set to

```
while($rang = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
{
    if ($rang['email'] == $rinse){
        echo $rang['email'];
    }

    $rinse = $rang['email'];
}
```